# Websocket client is receiving consecutive TEXT and PING messages appended in a single packet

Tags: c++, websocket, openssl, client, ping

I have implemented a secure websocket client (with OpenSSL encryption) in C++. The problem is, for received messages with size above 16k bytes, the client does not receive the ping message from server separately, rather the ping message is appended at the tail end of the preceding data message. As a result, the client does not parse the ping message, does not send a PONG reply and server closes the connection on timeout.

I am using a python based websocket server to test my client application. As far as I have tested, if the packet size sent from server is below 16k bytes, the pings are correctly received consistently during the test.

This is my read_from_websocket function

```
int read_from_websocket(char *recv_buff)
{
   uint buf_capacity = INT_MAX;
   uint  buf_offset   = 0;
   uint  read_count;

   do
   {
      read_count = ssl_read(recv_buff + buf_offset, buf_capacity);

      if (read_count == P_FD_ERR)  // P_FD_ERR = -1
      {
         return -1;
      }
      else if (read_count == P_FD_PENDING)  // P_FD_PENDING = -2
      {
         break;
      }

      if (read_count == 0)
      {
         break;  // EOF
      }

      buf_offset += read_count;
      buf_capacity -= read_count;

   } while (buf_capacity);

   return INT_MAX - buf_capacity;
}

/**SSL read function being called by the above websocket read function**/
int ssl_read(void *buf, size_t count)
{
   int len = SSL_read(ssl, buf, count);
   if (len < 0)
   {
      int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, len);

      if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
      {
         return P_FD_PENDING;
      }
      else
      {
         return P_FD_ERR;
      }
   }

   return len;
}
```

I don't understand:

- how to ensure that a single call to `read_from_websocket()` always returns only one complete message
- why does this only happen in case of incoming ping messages and only when the preceding message is greater than 16k bytes long
- whether the server side can be a culprit here since I'm using an [off-the-shelf server code](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

Comment: What's your question exactly? Can you fix the client's message parsing logic so it correctly locates the message boundaries? It's the client's job to find the boundaries between messages and process each one individually -- if it's not doing that, fix it so it does.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've edited the post a bit to clarify where I'm stuck. Yes we can identify the boundaries after parsing the payload length, but I'm trying to understand why this specific case arises in the first place. If it's a natural situation in websocket implementation then I'll move towards extracting multiple messages from a single received buffer.

Comment: It's definitely natural. Only the message parsing code knows where the message boundaries are. How could TLS know? How could TCP know? You need to fix the message parser to parse the mesages.